# make org-agenda-mode always have (org-agenda-follow-mode) toggled on

Tags: org-mode

I want to make it so that org-agenda-mode defaults to always having (org-agenda-follow-mode) toggled on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the variable `org-agenda-start-with-follow-mode`.

Comment: Thanks, you're my savior. I was trying to call (org-agenda-follow-mode) in my org-agenda-mode-hook to no avail.

Comment: @AlexBaranosky `(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook #'org-agenda-follow-mode)` works for me. Is that what you were trying?

Comment: @Malabarba I was doing (add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook 'org-agenda-follow-mode) if I recall correctly.